# Webpage not displaying correctly on every browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

What i want to do to make my pages open correctly on every size screen of monitor and display commonly in all browser. My website working fine in IE 8 and IE 9 without compatibility view but 
 my pages content get displace and get fuzzy when i open in IE 10. With compatibility view it is working fine in IE 10  but i can't force my customers to set compatibility when they open my website in IE 10.
 please provide me a solution as soon as possible.

Comment: Please post your code !!

Comment: @bipen I suppose OP simply doesn't know how hard it is to make pages look identical across browsers. Or he's a quite fat troll.

Comment: Initially the website was designed for IE 8 and 9.But now when IE 10 has arrived ,the content in the website gets displaced and fuzzy.However,when compatibility view is switched on it works fine. Please suggest me a method to make my website to work well in IE 10 without compatibility view.

Comment: @Rajthilak You need to be specific. What is fuzzy? images? css problem? The experts are not magician. You need to tell what is wrong in your code.

Comment: use this in code's `head` tag :- `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` This will force your IE to switch in IE8 even if it is IE10. I don't recommend this but I think you are actually looking for this.

Comment: @Mr_Green thanks lot.. Temporarily i will use "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />" to satisfy my customer and soon i will figure out wats goin wrong in IE10..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *only* solution is to open your page in all browsers you are going to support and check that it really renders everywhere *mostly* correctly. 99.9% probability that you will not be able to reach pixel-perfect identical rendering.

After you have found any discrepancy in some specific browser you open the development tools in this browser and search what CSS rule fails. After that you google about this issue seeking what browser-agnostic (if you're lucky) or browser-specific (in most cases) hack you should introduce. After that, you change your CSS accordingly.

Repeat this method until you get satisfying result in all browsers you are going to support. Of course if your website is javascript-heavy, you have to check that all behavior on your page is identical across all browsers you are going to support.

There's no silver bullet to instantly make your website look identically in all browsers.